# Sudo command for restart in Rails 4, Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

There is some piece of deploy.rb:

```
namespace :deploy do

  desc 'Restart application'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      # Your restart mechanism here, for example:
      # execute :touch, release_path.join('tmp/restart.txt')
      sudo "service nginx restart"
    end
  end

  after :publishing, :restart
end
```

As you can see, I want to restart my Nginx server after publishing. But I get the following error:

```
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Command::Failed: sudo exit status: 1
sudo stdout: Nothing written
sudo stderr: sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

As I understand I need to specify password for sudo command; but I don't store password in code, I use SSH for it. Am I wrong? How can I fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails - Nginx needs to be restarted after deploying with Capistrano?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11939540/rails-nginx-needs-to-be-restarted-after-deploying-with-capistrano)

Answer (score 7):

Capistrano 3 does not support sudo with password, and you cannot use sudo with password in Capistrano task with only Capistrano 3 gem.

However, I created a gem, [sshkit-sudo](https://github.com/kentaroi/sshkit-sudo), which is an SSHKit extension for sudo with password input (Capistrano 3 depends on SSHKit).

Add `gem 'sshkit-sudo'` to your application's Gemfile, `bundle install`, and add `require 'sshkit/sudo'` to your application's Capfile.

Then your code will work without change.